# calculate residual motion using opencv

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

According to the paper: Deep Learning for Saliency Prediction in Natural Video. Add 'Residual Motion' as the forth channel of a RGB image will improve the performance of saliency detection. 
I want to use opencv to calculate the 'Residual Motion' of videos.
According to the formula int paper:

The 'Residual Motion' is calculated by:

'Global motion estimation' - 'Optical flow estimation'

In opencv, there is a function can calculate the 'optical flow', can some one help to find some code to do it. I hope the code is written in python.

Comment: This question seems a little broad.  StackOverflow is best used when you have code and need help with troubleshooting it, or a specific question about how/why a part is working.

Comment: When I type "opencv optical flow" into Google, the first hit I get is the official OpenCV tutorial page showing how to calculate optical flow using Python. I can't imagine what you're asking.